# Email any event occuring on my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I own a TP-LINK WR841N router, which all my family members have access to (they know the password of the web interface).

What I want is that every time someone logs in or a password is changed an email is sent to me with detailed information about the event, and - if there is a password change - the new password.

Another option would be a kind of master password or a rights management system (like with Git servers where you can add a SSH key so others can push or pull without the need of a password).

Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your latter question about Git-like passwordless public key authentication.

Many Wi-Fi access points (wireless routers) support IEEE 802.1X authentication, often as part of a bigger set of security protocols known as *WPA2 Enterprise*. 802.1X allows unique per-user login credentials. Typically these credentials are checked by a separate authentication server, which the AP reaches via the RADIUS protocol. IEEE 802.1X and RADIUS act like conduits for any of a number of specific authentication methods, including one called EAP-TLS. EAP-TLS allows for user authentication via public key certificate (and the matching private key, of course).

So the most standards-based way to have passwordless per-user credentials is to set up WPA2-Enterprise with a RADIUS server, and EAP-TLS authentication with per user (or per-device) public key certificates.

It's hell to set up, though.

Answer (score 0):

It was not stated clearly enough, but I assume the question is how to monitor or limit the access to router configuration, not to Wi-Fi.

> Is any of this possible?

**Yes, in general.** I guess tricks like these may be easier with alternative firmware (like *dd-wrt*, *OpenWRT* -- I have some experience with the latter) than with the original one. With alternative firmware you may give yourself ssh access while leaving http interface to your family. **A command line interface available via ssh will give you more power.** Just remember: with great power comes great responsibility.

**There is a catch, though.** Since it is very uncommon to have limited user in home router OS, it may be hard to login a non-root user with http interface (thus allowing them to change a subset of options only). **Unless you cut your family off from http configuration** or find (or create) a firmware with explicit support for limited user **they will be able to alter your setup.** If you need a master password as a mean of recovery in case your family forgets their password -- it's fine. If you need everlasting access no matter what they do -- not so easy.

Issues to consider:

1. The firmware will probably use the same password (i.e. root password) for http and ssh access, so to gain an *exclusive* ssh access you may need to do some reconfiguration (see below) or to use key-based authentication.
2. The firmware will probably expose ssh settings via http interface. It may be tricky to make sure your family cannot mess with your ssh setup.
3. The http interface may expose greater number of advanced settings to users (in comparison to original firmware; no wonder, it is its job). These settings, while misused, may brick the device.
4. You may find that CLI requires more learning effort than GUI.

**You should do some research to learn which alternative firmware (if any) is right for you and your hardware. Use it at your own risk -- or don't.**

---

Below there are hints on how you may circumvent some of the above issues **in already working *OpenWRT***. They require some knowledge in Linux field.

1. Enable ssh, login via ssh as `root`.
2. Create non-root user by directly editing `/etc/passwd`.
3. Make the user a sudoer by directly editing `/etc/sudoers`.
4. Use `passwd` to set a password for the user. This will be your master password; it cannot be easily changed via http interface.
5. Make sure you can login via ssh as the new user; make sure the user can `sudo`.
6. *Dropbear* is ssh server, study [its options](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dropbear). Notice `RootLogin` option. Use it to disable ssh logins as root.

Still your family has root access via http. By default there is no easy way for them to execute arbitrary command (it needs `luci-app-commands` to be installed), but they may:

- disable ssh server,
- block ssh server on firewall level,
- execute a command with a cron job.

That's more than enough to make your master password useless.